# How to center text not including hyphen?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, hyphenation

The title of the book placed on the spine needs to be centered. The title includes hyphen - according to Czech standards, the hyphen should be placed also in front of the second word (f.e. in Icelandic-Czech). I am seeking advice how to center the text without including the repeating hyphen and if possible how to smaller the hyphen that does not look good.

Note: Only hyphens between Icelandic-Czech and Íslensk-tékknesk needs to be repeated (not stúdenta-orðabók)

```
\documentclass[8pt,
    marklength=20mm,
    coverwidth=162mm,
    coverheight=229mm,
    bleedwidth=30mm,spinewidth=65mm]{bookcover}

\usepackage[icelandic, latin, czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgpagella}
% #################################################################### COLORS #

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor {title}              {RGB} {  16,   13,   32}

% #################################################################### LAYOUT #

% \normalsize should be {8pt}{9.6pt}
\def\HUGE {\fontsize{23.887872pt}{3\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\Huge {\fontsize{19.906560pt}{3\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\huge {\fontsize{16.588800pt}{3\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\LARGE{\fontsize{13.824000pt}{2\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\Large{\fontsize{11.520000pt}{2\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\large{\fontsize{ 9.600000pt}{2\baselineskip}\selectfont}

% Two columns layout ruler
\setlength\columnsep    {2\baselineskip}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

% Necessary for baseline alignment
\topskip=\baselineskip
\raggedbottom
\setlength\parskip{0pt} % it's better to avoid glue

% Temporarily suppress warnings
\hbadness=5000
\vbadness=5000

\setlength\emergencystretch{17pt}

% Allow smaller emergencystretch in several cases
\newenvironment{xtolerant}[2]{%
  \par
  \ifx\empty#1\empty\else\tolerance=#1\relax\fi
  \ifx\empty#2\empty\else\emergencystretch=#2\relax\fi
}{%
  \par
}

 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}

\def\dictnameCZ{islandsko-český studijní slovník}
\def\dictnameIS{íslensk-tékknesk stúdentaorðabók}

\begin{document}

%back cover
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{back}{%
color=title,
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{back}{%
\vspace{2cm}
\centering
}

%front cover
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{front}{%
color=title,
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{front}{%
\centering
\vspace{2cm}
{\Huge\scshape\color{white}%
   \dictnameCZ\\\dictnameIS}
}

%spine
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{spine}{%
color=title,
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{spine}{
\vspace{4cm}

\begin{center}\Huge\scshape\color{white}%
   islandsko-\\
   -český\\
   studijní\\
   slovník
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{0.1cm}%{\fill}

   \begin{center}\Huge\scshape\color{white}%
   íslensk-\\
   -tékknesk\\
   stúdenta-\\
   orðabók
   \end{center}

   \vspace*{10cm}%{\fill}

\begin{center}
{\color{white}www.hvalur.org}
\end{center}

\vfill}

\makebookcover
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see a hyphen at the end of the line and  hyphen at the start of the new line. But only one for studenta-ordabok. This seems to be what you want, already.

Comment: Yes, it is correct but the text is centered with the hyphens. I am not sure, but centering only the words (without hyphens) it would look better, imho.

Comment: unrelated to your hyphen question but your definitions for `\large` and friends are incorrect. `\normalsize\huge abc` should be the same as `\Large\huge abc`  but will not be as you have defined `\huge` to triple the current value of `\baselineskip` so the second case will have 6 times a normal skip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the width of the hyphen, but i am not sure it looks much better.

```
\documentclass[8pt,
    marklength=20mm,
    coverwidth=162mm,
    coverheight=229mm,
bleedwidth=30mm,spinewidth=65mm]{bookcover}

\usepackage[icelandic, latin, czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgpagella}
            % #################################################################### COLORS #

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor {title}              {RGB} {  16,   13,   32}

            % #################################################################### LAYOUT #

            % \normalsize should be {8pt}{9.6pt}
\def\HUGE {\fontsize{23.887872pt}{3\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\Huge {\fontsize{19.906560pt}{3\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\huge {\fontsize{16.588800pt}{3\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\LARGE{\fontsize{13.824000pt}{2\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\Large{\fontsize{11.520000pt}{2\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\def\large{\fontsize{ 9.600000pt}{2\baselineskip}\selectfont}

            % Two columns layout ruler
\setlength\columnsep    {2\baselineskip}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

            % Necessary for baseline alignment
\topskip=\baselineskip
\raggedbottom
\setlength\parskip{0pt} % it's better to avoid glue

            % Temporarily suppress warnings
\hbadness=5000
\vbadness=5000

\setlength\emergencystretch{17pt}

            % Allow smaller emergencystretch in several cases
\newenvironment{xtolerant}[2]{%
    \par
    \ifx\empty#1\empty\else\tolerance=#1\relax\fi
    \ifx\empty#2\empty\else\emergencystretch=#2\relax\fi
}{%
    \par
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}

\def\dictnameCZ{islandsko-český studijní slovník}
\def\dictnameIS{íslensk-tékknesk stúdentaorðabók}

\begin{document}

                 %back cover
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{back}{%
    color=title,
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{back}{%
    \vspace{2cm}
    \centering
}

                 %front cover
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{front}{%
    color=title,
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{front}{%
    \centering
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Huge\scshape\color{white}%
\dictnameCZ\\\dictnameIS}
                    }

                    %spine
                    \setbookcover{bgcolor}{spine}{%
                        color=title,
                    }

                    \setbookcover{fgfirst}{spine}{
                        \vspace{4cm}

                        \begin{center}\Huge\scshape\color{white}%
                            islandsko\rlap{-}\\
                            -český\\
                            studijní\\
                            slovník

                        \vspace*{1cm}%{\fill}

                            íslensk\rlap{-}\\
                            \mbox{}\llap{-}tékknesk\\
                            stúdenta-\\
                            orðabók

                        \vspace*{10cm}%{\fill}

                            {\color{white}www.hvalur.org}
                        \end{center}

                    \vfill}

                    \makebookcover
                    \end{document}
```

Parts of your code are a bit weird.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to smaller (shorten) the hyphens? It might be better then title with a lot of large hyphens. In many cases, the dictionary authors do not include hyphen at all, but that is typographical mistake.

Comment: You can do `\newcommand{\czHyphen}{\rule[.45ex]{.2em}{.15ex}}`, but really, font design is a craft and an art. Better not mess with the artists work.